# Specific Vim Typing Color

Tags: vim, syntax, colors, terminal

Im using VIM in the OSX terminal. I load the "DarkBlue" colorscheme but with a few configurations. My problem is getting the "writing color" white, but keeping the purple color of the functions.

Here is my color configurations in my .vimrc file:

```
" ================ Colors ========================
colo DarkBlue   
syntax on
hi Comment      ctermfg=White
hi Directory    ctermfg=White
hi Identifier   ctermfg=White
hi PreProc      ctermfg=White
hi Title        ctermfg=White
hi LineNr       ctermfg=White
```

If I add this to my .vimrc file, the writing color turns white, but purple gets white as well.

```
"hi Constant    ctermfg=White"
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What happens, if you type in Vim `:hi Function`? Because in my darkblue colorsheme the colour of function is set on DeepSkyBlue1 (`ctermfg=39`), so it sounds strange to try to keep the colour of the functions purple, if it is not actually purple.

Comment: Also, if something changed after `hi Constant    ctermfg=White`, it is because Boolean, Character, Float, Number and String are linked into one highlight group, i.e. to Constant.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with a javascript file (i.e. extension `.js`):

`hi Function  ctermfg=Magenta`

It colors the `function` keyword and delimiters.